# Not able to run code in Flask framework with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am running a very simple program in python with flask framework.

```
from flask import Flask  
app=Flask(__name__)  
@app.route('/seconds')  
def hello_world():  
return 'Hello Vish'  

if __name__=='__main__':  
app.run()
```

when i ran the program for the first time i can correctly, later i edited the code and ran again,
I was getting the below message without any furthur movement,

Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

later i used
     app.run(debug=True)
     instead of 
     app.run()
then i was receiving below 2 message and struck over there,

Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
Restarting with stat

Could anyone help me in this regard?

Comment: What *"furthur movement"* did you expect? Did you make a request to the specified endpoint?

Comment: @jonrsharpe , I checked at the  _http://127.0.0.1:5000/seconds_ , it was displaying an error message(Not Found,The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.)

Comment: @Vishwa I can't reproduce the error you're getting. I copy and pasted your code, ran it and accessed http://127.0.0.1:5000/seconds and it displayed "Hello Vish".

Comment: I really dont have the problem with the code.I am facing the issue while i am executing it.    

I am using spyder as a IDE to run the programs.     
Afer the running the code i will check the output in http://localhost:5000/xyz,it looks fine.  
I will edit the code re run again then there will not be any output,it shows as "Not found".  

then i need to restart system to re run the code,then works fine.  

I stopped the debugger using Ctrl+C,which most of the time it doesnt work.  
I tried restarting the kernel,sometimes it works and sometime it doesnt.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked the solution for my question.
I was manually killing the Python processes in the "Task manager" window.
thus i was able to run the furthur queries.

Thank s